# php and mysql date time difference

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I did this in php to store the lastlogin in a mysql datetime column

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s') //which then gave > '2014-01-04 08:00:56'
```

and then saved it

When I need to calculate users who have been online more than 20 minutes, I did this in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `elc_users`  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , lastlogin, NOW( ) ) <20
```

it didn't work, when I traced in mysql, `Now()` gave this > `2014-01-04 20:00:56`

Now this wont let me get my 20 minutes logged in users.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I inserted a record manually in phpMyAdmin, to be sure whthear its timezone issue in a `timestamp` column with default value `current_timestamp`, it gave `2014-01-05 06:48:21`. I the ran this query in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT created, NOW( )  `elc_users`
```

this gave `2014-01-05 18:53:53`

Now i also exec the code below to check the global and session timezone, and i got phpMyAdmin

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

which then gave `SYSTEM | SYSTEM`

Comment: Probably your mysql server has a different timezone.

Comment: this is on my dev machine, ok how can i avoid this time zone difference

Comment: @FilipGórny pls look at the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the date column and created it again.
this now recorded the time in the correct format

`timestamp` gave `2014-01-04 20:58:56`, and `NOW()` gave `2014-01-04 20:58:56`

thanks for all who contributed, this wasn't a timezone issue as @AbdulJabbarWebBestow mentioned

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Like Filip said it's probably a timezone issue; you can change the timezone of your script to whatever timezone your MySQL is set to like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: how can i detected this in a production server? Or if i set this in in php will it affect mysql

Comment: `select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'));` should return the mysql timezone for you

Comment: The other "hacky" way is to use php date in your query rather than mysql NOW()

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid such problems, check the following things.

1. Make sure that `system time` and `system timezone` of both the DB Server and the Application Server are same.
2. Make sure that you have set the configuration of PHP and MySQL to take proper time-zones.
3. Always use a single function to set update, insert rows that have a `dateTime` field in them. Personally, I suggest that you write a common function somewhere in your code, and whenever you need to get the current time, use that function, instead of using the MySQL's `NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this would be a timezone issue because PHP and MySQL both are running on same machine so both would be getting same time on calling current datetime. May be you can try this because I tried this on my machine as you said.

```
SELECT * FROM `elc_users` WHERE lastlogin < date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 MINUTE)
```

Comment: +1 for timezone issue because PHP and MySQL both are running on same machine. I don't know about query but I faced something like that and as @Abdul Jabbar WebBestow said It wasn't the timezone difference in PHP and MySQL

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks and you can check query by select date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 MINUTE) as it will give you -20 minutes from your current time and hence means it will give those records which are logged in last 20 minutes.

Comment: which are logged in for more than 20 minutes

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow why are the times different?